# Why is CMP an example of implicit addressing mode in 8085 microprocessor?

Tags: microprocessors, 8085

Definition of implicit addressing mode is:

This mode doesn’t require any operand; the data is specified by the opcode itself.

CMP B:

This instruction will compare B with A contents. Here, opcode is CMP and operand is B.

Then why is that CMP is an example of implicit addressing?

Comment: Is that a homework question? I'm not sure I could explain it any more clearly  than the text in your question could. Whatctly don't you understand?

Comment: Why is it implicit when it has operand??

Answer (score 0):

`cmp` is an example of implicit addressing, because the first operant (`A`) is selected automatically by the instruction instead of being explicitly specified in the code.